# Do Akka actorSelection path shortcuts exist?

Tags: java, akka

Java 8 and Akka 2.5.16 here. I have the following actor:

```
public class Guardian extends AbstractActor {
  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .matchAny(message -> {
            // Do stuff in here
        }).build();
  }
}
```

Which I create like so:

```
ActorRef guardian = context().actorOf(Props.create(Guardian.class), Guardian.class.getName());
String path = guardian.path().toString();

// Prints: "akka://myapp/user/com.me.myapp.Guardian"
log.info("path = {}", path);
```

I would now like to use `ActorSelection` to look up this existing actor:

```
String pathShortcut = "user/com.me.myappp.Guardian";
ActorSelection guardianSelection = context().actorSelection(pathShortcut);
```

Do I **need** to pass in the full (`akka://myapp/user/com.me.myapp.Guardian`) path value, or can I provide a shortcut like:

```
// Examples:
String pathShortcut1 = "user/com.me.myappp.Guardian";
String pathShortcut2 = "com.me.myapp.Guardian";
String pathShortcut3 = "Guardian";
```

In other words, does `context().actorSelection(...)` **require** a fully-qualified path or can it take shortcuts and intelligently resolve/infer them?

Also, will the "path protocol" *always* be `akka://` or does that change ever (say, with remote actors or other actor libraries)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "*no*", you must provide the full `akka://full/path/to/named/actor/instance` with `ActorSelections`.